# How will you find 3rd employees from the top with highest salary from each department

Tags: sql, oracle

How will you find 3rd emplyees from top with highest salary in each department in Oracle SQL?

```
Select * 
from 
    (select 
         emp-id, dept_id, 
         row_number (order by salary desc) rn 
     from 
         employee 
     group by 
         emp_id, dept_id, salary) 
where rn = 3
```

Comment: Use a partition: e.g. `row_number() over(partition by dept_id order by salary DESC)` also consider use of dense_rank() instead of row_number() if you want "equal 3rd"

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query you offered appears nearly accurate, but there are a couple of issues. The `GROUP BY` clause is unnecessary, and you must consider the rank (`rn`) within each department separately. You can accomplish this by utilizing the `PARTITION BY` clause along with the `ORDER BY` clause inside the `ROW_NUMBER()` function. Here's the rectified SQL query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        emp_id,
        dept_id,
        salary,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITIONED BY dept_id ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rn
    FROM
        employee
) ranked_employee
WHERE rn = 3;
```

In this query, the `ROW_NUMBER()` function generates a unique rank for each row within each department based on the descending order of salary. The `PARTITIONED BY dept_id` ensures that the ranking is done separately for each department. Then, in the outer query, we select the rows where the rank (`rn`) is equal to 3, which corresponds to the third employee from the top with the highest salary in each department.

Answer (score 0):

Use the analytic RANK ir DENSE_RANK function depending how you want to treat ties.

```
CREATE TABLE departments(  department_id, department_name) AS
SELECT 1, 'IT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Sales' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Marketing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Finance' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE employees (employee_id, first_name, last_name, hire_date, salary,  department_id) AS
SELECT 1, 'Lisa', 'Saladino', DATE '2001-04-03', 160000, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Sandy', 'Herring', DATE '2011-08-04', 150200, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Beth', 'Cooper', DATE '2019-03-05', 60700, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Carol', 'Orr', DATE '2007-11-11', 70125,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Vicky', 'Palazzo', DATE '2004-09-17', 68525,2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Cheryl', 'Ford', DATE '2020-05-10', 110000,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Leslee', 'Altman', DATE '2008-12-10', 66666, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'Jill', 'Coralnick', DATE '2001-04-11', 190000, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 'Faith', 'Aaron', DATE '2001-04-17', 122000,2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'Silvio', 'Dante', DATE '2022-10-16', 102150,4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'Jerry', 'Torchiano', DATE '2022-10-30', 112660,4 FROM DUAL;


select  rnk, last_name, department_id, salary 
from    (
    select  last_name, department_id, salary,
        RANK () OVER ( PARTITION BY  department_id
                   ORDER BY      salary DESC
                 ) AS rnk
    from    employees
    )
where   rnk = 3


RNK LAST_NAME DEPARTMENT_ID SALARY
3 Ford 1 110000
3 Palazzo 2 68525
```

Comment: I would use the `dense_rank` analytic function instead of `rank`, because if there are, say, 2 people with the second highest salary, you wouldn't get a rank of 3. See https://dbfiddle.uk/_p6JggFi for an example.